# Manage SNS Topic Metrics

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I've created many Metrics Topics and I want to edit and delete some. But couldn't find any way in console to do so.

- Is it possible somewhere in the Console?
- Is there are any APIS, commands I can use to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to manage your topics
Naviagte to SNS Console Management and you can manage them there

[SNS Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sns/)